# make div appear on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div `.description` that appears where the mouse is as it hovers over an element.

So far, I have this code for making the div appear in a fixed location:

```
$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(e) {
  // var to link tooltips and hand to description
  var target = $(this).attr('data-show');
         
  // hide current description if showing
  if ($('.description').is(':visible')) {
    $('.description').fadeOut(0);
  };
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#' + target).fadeIn(400);
});

$('body').mouseover(function(){
  $('.description').fadeOut(0);
});
```

It works fine, but instead of just have `.description` appear, I need it to appear where the mouse hovers.

I tried adding this function:

```
function divPosition (event){
  // pass mouse position to description div css
  $(".description").css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX- 200});
};
```

but it didn't work. I also tried adding the line within the function but i'm not sure how to pass the event argument.

Please see my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bns4zp1q/2/

Comment: `when the mouse hovers.` or **where** the mouse hover?

Comment: can you share your html/css code?

Comment: Share the HTML and CSS also.

Comment: Sorry, it is **where**. I will share my CSS / HTML shortly

Comment: Hi, please see JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bns4zp1q/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `mousemove` event, and use your `divPosition` function.

https://jsfiddle.net/agbuLop1/

```
$('.tooltip').mousemove(divPosition);

function divPosition (event){
  // pass mouse position to description div css
  $(".description").css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX- 200});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the description really have to follow the mouse movement or just appear at hovered circle? Here is a quick and dirty **example without javascript**:

https://jsfiddle.net/k9jpqom2/1/

(new) HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip-container">
    <div class="image" id="machine1">
        <img src="http://axevilw.sellamachine.com/EnhFiles/advert/182/Machine.jpg/Machine.jpg">
        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip1" data-show="description1">1
           <div class="description-container">
             <div class="description" id="description1">
                LED Strip Lighting
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(additional) CSS

```
.description-container {  
    width:1px;height:1px;position:relative;
}
#tooltip1:hover .description {
    display:block;
    width:10em;
    position:absolute;
    left:-4em;
    height:auto;
}
.tooltip{
    width:5%;
    height: 6%;
    }
```

**If you don't want to edit the HTML** you can try something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/g2p5g2r4/2/

```
.tooltip .description-container {  
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
}

#tooltip1:hover + .description-container #description1 {
    display:block;
    width:10em;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    top: 36%;
    left: 25%;
}
#tooltip1 { 
    top: 31%;
}
```

You will have to fine tune the position of #description1, #description2, etc...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is really good, and I much prefer the CSS only method in this example. Only thing is it would mean re-organising all of the HTML elements which could be quite bothersome for the application.

Comment: See updated answer. (Also remember that :hover will not work the same way on touch-screens)